# Google Drive muestra Información del Archivo pero el archivo 'no existe'

Tags: batch, google-drive

Les comento, esto intentando copiar una carpeta pública de Google Drive usando un .bat y Drive File Stream, que simula una unidad en mi PC con mis carpetas de Google Drive.

Si bien algunas carpetas aparecen vacías, a partir de un punto hay algunos archivos que no se copian pero sí me da información de ese archivo (Peso, nombre, extensión). Al revisar en Drive online las carpetas aparecen vacías. Pensé que quizá fuese un bloqueo a mi IP por el volumen de descarga que llevo, pero probé con el celular sin WIFI y tampoco aparecen.

La carpeta en cuestión es esta:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/17nemAYjxYpXjWD1iQCGoRfA0n1uBgkrU
Y el código del batch es el siguiente

```
@echo off
CHCP 65001
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (
  set _date=%%a%%b%%c
  )
robocopy "G:\.shortcut-targets-by-id\17nemAYjxYpXjWD1iQCGoRfA0n1uBgkrU\+ P L ∆ t $ i" "G:\Mi unidad\- Copia Platzi" /e /z /unilog+:"CopyLog.txt" /tee
```

En la captura se ve cómo un archivo se copia hasta un cierto porcentaje (siempre 37.7) y ya los siguientes no se copian, aunque sí muestra la info del archivo.

[image: En este punto empieza el problema]

Alguna idea?? Gracias desde ya

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. ¿A qué te refieres con carpeta pública de Google Drive?

Comment: Hola @Rubén. Muchas gracias!Me refiero a una carpeta compartida con cualquier persona que tenga el enlace. En este caso con permiso de lectura

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al parecer se han borrado algunos archivos de su ubicación original.
La información acerca de estos archivos fantasma probablemente se haya copiado como reserva previo a la descarga de su contenido, ya que se encuentran en Mi Unidad de Drive File Stream, ocupando espacio en disco, pero no abren. Al intentar copiarlos manualmente al escritorio me sale el mensaje

[image: Error de Windows: No se encontró el elemento]

De todas formas no hace al problema original ni a una solución.

Answer (score 0):

Antes de empezar asegúrate que el disco duro de tu equipo tiene suficiente espacio para descargar todos los archivos de la carpeta en cuestión. Si cuenta con el suficiente espacio, continúa

1. Asegúrate que la carpeta se encuentra en "Mi Unidad" o una unidad de equipo
2. Usando el explorador de Windows localiza la carpeta, haz clic con el botón derecho y seleccione Disponible sin conexión
3. Espera a que se descarguen todos los archivos
4. Intenta de nuevo ejecutar el código del batch

Comment: Hola de nuevo Rubén, gracias por tu tiempo.Te comento, revisando la carpeta de Drive en cuestión veo que pesa cada vez menos, por lo que es probable que se estén eliminando los archivos progresivamente. Me sigue haciendo ruido esto de que a pesar de eso, el batch siga teniendo la información de nombre, ubicación y peso de archivos, pero aún sabiendo el por qué, no llega a ser una solución al problema ahora que ya no existen. Voy a dar el tema por solucionado. Gracias nuevamente!

Comment: @FedeGómez ¿Te refieres a que en la carpeta original se están eliminando?

Comment: Sí, la carpeta no es mía..al entrar en Drive por Chrome el peso de la carpeta completa y la cantidad de archivos es menor de lo que yo ya respaldé en mi PC, y faltan los últimos archivos que copié, unos 10gB aprox..Lo raro es que los archivos que faltan sí están en mi PC (Mi Unidad offline de DFS) ocupando espacio en disco, pero son copias fallidas, como indico en la respuesta que hice. Desconozco si estas copias se han hecho de algún 'metadato' de Drive  y ahí quedaron los datos de los archivos con su espacio reservado.